# How to select raw table with one class (class :odd,even)

Tags: jquery

I have table where odd lines have the class '`class_odd`', and even lines have the class '`class_even`'.

I need to select the tr which contains the line that can contain `class_odd` or `class_even` on the table by clicking.

How can I add to `$(".class_tr").click(function()`class_odd and class_even instead one class `class_tr`?

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".class_tr").click(function()
//do something
{
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So... what you're saying is you're looking for `$(".class_odd, .class_even")`?